# how do I fix website speed error: Your page is not using font-display rule when loading the following web fonts?

Tags: wordpress, web

Keep getting this error: Your page is not using font-display rule when loading the following web fonts.

Possible fix: How to fix, but not sure where to put. Please help...

To add the font-display property for Google Fonts, you can pass the desired value in the query string display parameter as shown in the example below:

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?display=swap&family=Roboto&display=swap

Comment: Would you be able to show us the code you use to load the web fonts?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure where to pull that from? We currently use divi builder in our wordpress site.